# Bootanimation is changed but the official logo of penta is show

Tags: 4.4-kitkat

I have just remove my official boot animation & the new animation is work but the logo of company is show when before boot animation.

I have Penta t-pad callpro3G.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your updated description, you're referring to the 1st screen (sometimes called "splash"). It's encoded and built into a separate partition of the device (not `/system`), which can't be changed easily. Only on popular devices can devs bother to figure out the location and the format of the stored logo, thus making it accessible to us modders.

Comment: Well, most modern phones have a separate partition named `splash`.

Comment: Thanks dude. I'll not find a splash folder but the pref_splash.XML and startappsplash.HTML present in my phone

Comment: @iBug There's a guide on XDA that I subscribed to, which supposedly tells you where to look for splash partitions on Qualcomm devices, but in reality I can't find it on most of my devices (I have quite a handful). Also, determining the storage format is another challenge in itself.